# Notice: Undefined index: Segmentation in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have used MongoDB with PHP i have to tried to get document from Mongo collection With folowing PHP code
PHP CODE

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('trends.trends_new_collection', $query);
$cursor->setTypeMap(['root' => 'array']);

$doc = $cursor->toArray();

echo "<pre>";print_r($doc['Segmentation']);echo "</pre>";
```

if i use `echo "<pre>";print_r($doc);echo "</pre>";` i got result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 1
            [Trends] => Youthful Truths
            [Segmentation] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Lifestyle] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [SEC] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SEC A
                                )

                            [LSM] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [10-12] => 235
                                    [13-15] => 585
                                    [16-18] => 525
                                )

                        )

                    [Generation] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Global] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Gen Z
                                    [1] => Millennials
                                    [2] => Gen X
                                )

                            [India] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Gen Z
                                    [1] => Millennials
                                    [2] => Liberalized Gen
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Location] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Global] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Country] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => india
                        )

                    [UrbanRural] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => urban
                        )

                )

            [Relevance] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [HoriZontal] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Marketing
                            [1] => Branding
                        )

                )
...etc
```

if i use `echo "<pre>";print_r($doc['Segmentation']);echo "</pre>";` i gor error
`Notice:  Undefined index: segmentation in` How to access 'stdClass Object'? How to access this result in Php with Mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 2D array. 
Please use `echo $doc[0]['Segmentation'];`

**Method 2:-**

```
$doc = json_decode(json_encode($doc), true);

echo $doc['Segmentation'];
```

Comment: K V It has worked but How to access `stdClass Object`?

Comment: Try as follows `$value = $doc (array);`